# Unity 3D camera jitter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I have a complete movement script functioning in the game and a look around script that should work perfectly but it doesn't, perhaps it is unity of my code, but anytime I try to look around my camera instantly goes back to looking forward  no matter how much I move it. I haven't added the x axis rotation yet because I would like it to get working now instead wasting time writing something that won't work.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Look : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform player;
    public Transform cams;

    public float xSensitivity;
    public float ySensitivity;
    public float maxAngle;
    
    void Update()
    {
        SetY();
    }

    void SetY()
    {
        float t_input = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        Quaternion t_adj = Quaternion.AngleAxis(t_input, -Vector3.right);
        Quaternion t_delta = cams.localRotation = t_adj;
        cams.localRotation = t_delta;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this question, it isn't directly asked what is your Camera Type? but according to your efforts in the above codes, I guessed that you are looking for **POV**. Therefore, before completing the codes, consider a pivot point for your camera as an empty game object that faces the player.

[image: Pivot]

Now, replace the following code sample and add it to **MainCamera** Object to see the soft camera with the ability to limit, I hope it will solve your problem.

```cs
public float xSensitivity = 1f;
public float ySensitivity = 1f;
public float sharpness = 15;
public float maxAngle = 30f;

private float yAxis, currentYAxis, xAxis, currentXAxis, _sharpness;
void Update()
{
    yAxis -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySensitivity;
    xAxis += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSensitivity;

    _sharpness = 1 - Mathf.Exp(-sharpness * Time.deltaTime);
    
    currentXAxis = Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.LerpAngle(currentXAxis, xAxis, _sharpness), -maxAngle, maxAngle);
    currentYAxis = Mathf.Clamp(Mathf.LerpAngle(currentYAxis, yAxis, _sharpness), -maxAngle, maxAngle);
    
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(currentYAxis, currentXAxis);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it seems I was not clear, I am not using the main camera but a secondary camera for the player, and it seems this code did not function at all.

Comment: @Ivanoo Never use two cameras because it reduces fps to a great extent. Place this code on any camera that moves with mouse movement, but because it uses localEuler, put a pivot under the camera.